# How many children does Bruce Wayne have?

Tags: dc, batman

Recently I was reading something on the internet about Batman, and they mention his daughter, Helena Wayne, which he had with Selina Kyle. There is also Damian, a son he had with Talia al Ghul. I also vaguely remember he had more children in "Superman & Batman Generations."

Does he have any other children?

Comment: Ah yes, throw away progeny that conveniently appear when the plot needs one.  So much easier to write than 20 years of fidelity, commitment and responsibility.

Comment: @RBarryYoung - The guy's a billionaire playboy with a penchant for loose women, [fine alcohol](http://www.smoothred.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/begins308.jpg) and [amnesia-causing head injuries](https://ultraboy8888.files.wordpress.com/2014/12/tec_228_001.png). I'm surprised that he hasn't got more illegitimate offspring crawling out of the woodwork waving paternity test lawsuits.

Comment: [Two in every state](https://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/delasoul/talkinboutheylove.html).

Answer (score 33, accepted):

There are many .......

[**Ibn al Xu'ffasch (Earth-22)**](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Ibn_al_Xu'ffasch_(Earth-22))

Ibn al Xu'ffasch is the adult illegitimate son of Batman and Talia al Ghul who is usually noted to have developed on alternate Earths. In most of these other alternate realities, Ibn is sired against Wayne's full knowledge or in one instance directly against Wayne's will as his mother desired to enslave the Batman to her will, Talia drugged Wayne, and forced herself upon him. The product of their evening together was Ibn al Xu'ffasch. Talia kept Ibn's existence a secret from the Dark Knight, and Batman never learned the truth behind Ibn's parentage.

[Terry McGinnis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batman_(Terry_McGinnis)) ([DCAU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DC_animated_universe))

Amanda Waller used nanotechnology to ensure that Bruce Wayne's DNA overwrote the DNA in Warren McGinnis's sex cells. Making him his biological son.

[Huntress (Helena Wayne) {Earth 2}](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huntress_(Helena_Wayne))

Helena was born in 1957 to Bruce Wayne and Selina Kyle Wayne, and grew up enjoying the benefits of being in a wealthy household. In 1976, criminal Silky Cernak blackmailed his old boss Selina Kyle into resuming action once again as Catwoman, an act which eventually led to her death. Helena, deciding to bring Cernak to justice, created a costume for herself, fashioned some weapons from her parents' equipment (including her eventual trademark, a crossbow), and set out to bring him in. After accomplishing this, Helena decided to continue to fight crime, under the code name "the Huntress."

**[Tallant Wayne](http://www.comicvine.com/tallant/4005-7656/)**

The son of both Bruce Wayne and Talia in the Elseworlds world of Batman: league of batman.

[Damian Wayne](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Damian_Wayne)

Damian's origin is unknown to Batman. Genetically perfected and grown in an artificial womb, Damian was intended to be a formidable warrior. He is raised by Talia and the League of Assassins. He becomes a talented martial artist by the time he is a pre-teen, at which time Talia reveals Damian's existence to Bruce Wayne and leaves him in Batman's custody in an effort to disrupt Batman's work.

[Bruce Wayne Jr. (Earth-154)](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Bruce_Wayne,_Jr._(Earth-154))

Bruce Wayne, Jr. was the biological son of Bruce Wayne of an alternate reality in which the elder Wayne married and had children. Bruce Wayne Jr. did not truly appreciate his father's legacy, although he did train to the same levels both physically and mentally (as did Dick Grayson, who became Wayne, Sr.'s junior partner Robin).

[Bruce Wayne, Jr. (Earth-3839)](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Bruce_Wayne,_Jr._(Earth-3839))

Bruce Wayne Jr. was born the son of Bruce Wayne (Batman) and the wife he married around 1949. As a young child he was impressed by his father being Batman and his "Uncle Dick" Grayson being Robin, so much to the point where Alfred the butler found him in the Batcave wearing his uncle's Robin outfit and doing exercises in the hopes of someday becoming the Boy Wonder. His mother, however, wanted Bruce Jr. to not take on the identity of Robin until he was eighteen. Despite her wishes, Bruce Jr. became Robin and worked alongside Clark Kent's (Superman) daughter Kara who became Supergirl in their teens. His eventual partnership with Dick Grayson as Batman was what drove his mother away.

He has  two adopted son too [Tim Drake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tim_Drake) (third robin) and [Clark Wayne](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Clark_Wayne_(Earth-3839)). But only Damian is from main continuity, not sure about Terry's comic counterpart.

Comment: “Hi, I’m Batman, and these are my sons. This is Ibn al Xu'ffasch.” “Cool. What’s the other one’s name?” “Terry.”

Comment: Regarding Ibn, "Talia drugged Wayne, and forced herself upon him". That's horrifying! (And just as bad as it would be if their roles were reversed).

Comment: @BBlake It will create confusion when two player have same name.

Comment: Did you know that in Arabic (as well as Persian) "Xu'ffasch" literally means "bat", and "Ibn" means "son of", so Batman's son's name is "Son of the Bat".

Comment: @mooz nice information

Comment: @Mooz: so “Terry” actually has the more creative name? I feel like Batman isn’t the most enthusiastic father.

Comment: @Paul Oh the irony!

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Because he didn't named Terry

Comment: You put a * after Terry McGinnus, but then never qualified that * with a footnote.

Comment: @JackBNimble it's clickable

Comment: @TerryMcGinnis That seems like a strange way to do that. You don't qualify any of the other universes with their own tiny links. I would think it would make more sense to link to the character with the name, and then the universe with the (universe) text. But whatever.

Comment: @JackBNimble ok I will think about it, already planning to update the answer as I read links where it’s claimed he adopted more people here and there.

Comment: @JackBNimble fixed

Comment: @Möoz So, Ibn al Xu'ffasch is a Batson, like [Billy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captain_Marvel_(DC_Comics))?

Comment: _Exactly_ @Chronocidal!

Answer (score 3):

Okay, there are many continuities and offspring in the DC universes. I'm going to consider only the ones in the *Rebirth* and the *New 52*.

- **Dick Grayson**: His parents died at the hands of Tony Zucco, and Bruce was at the event where Dick's parent's act was rigged by Zucco. Dick became the first Robin, adoptive son of Bruce, then later Nightwing.
- **Jason Todd**: Criminal father, dead mother, (basically an orphan), tries to steal tires from Bruce's Batmobile, to gain money from them. Bruce took him in. He became the second Robin, dying at the hands of the Joker. He took a dip in the Lazarus pit, bringing him back to life so Talia Al G'hul could train and use him against Batman. Is now the Red Hood.
- **Tim Drake**: Found out Batman was Bruce Wayne, Bruce took him in. Third Robin. Becomes Red Robin.
- **Damian Wayne**: Talia basically raped Bruce, and Damian was born from an artificial womb. He was introduced to Batman after Deathstroke (Slade Wilson) killed Ras Al G'hul. Fifth Robin.
- **Cassandra Cain**: Daughter of assassin David Cain and Lady Shiva. Sentenced to a brutal training regime by her father, barely ever allowed to speak. Pre-Flashpoint: Second Batgirl (first Batgirl: Barbara Gordon), becomes Black Bat. Post-Flashpoint, she's known as Orphan; it's unclear what (if any) of her pre-Flashpoint history is intact.

While Damian is Batman's only biological son, at some point each of the others were adopted by Batman; again, it's not completely clear if that holds true post-Flashpoint.

Other offspring:

- **Helena Wayne**: Selena Kyle and Bruce Wayne's daughter on Earth 2. Comes to New Earth (the main DC universe), becomes Huntress. Not to be confused with the post-Flashpoint Helena Bertinelli who we first meet working as an agent of Spyral (working with Dick Grayson in *Grayson*), and who takes up the name Huntress after Helena Wayne returns to Earth 2. She mostly appeared in that guise in the Rebirth version of *Birds of Prey*, with Batgirl (Barbara Gordon) and Black Canary (Dinah Drake-Lance).
- **Terry McGinnis**: I'm not sure what universe he's from. But, in the future (when Bruce is an old man), he becomes Batman (as seen in *Batman Beyond*). According to the DC animated universe (as seen in the *Justice League* cartoon from the early 2000s), Amanda Waller claims that, due to weird genetic science trickery, he is biologically the son of Bruce Wayne; I don't believe the comics have ever addressed this.

Honorable mention: the following two characters have been Robin at some point; however, I don't believe either has been adopted by Bruce Wayne:

- **Stephanie Brown**: Post-Flashpoint, we've only seen her as Spoiler; however, for a short period of time pre-Flashpoint, she was the first female Robin (chronologically, at least).
- **Carrie Kelly**: We shouldn't really include her, because she's not in continuity of *Rebirth* (at least, not as the first female Robin she's not. She's a college student who knows Batman is Bruce Wayne. Anyways...). She's best known as taking on the Robin role when Bruce Wayne comes out of retirement in the classic *The Dark Knight Returns* graphic novel by Frank Miller.

Comment: Can you provide any sources for your answer? It is recommended that you support your answer with as much evidence to show proof your answer is valid and not just an assumption you've made.

Comment: Now, _I_ know this answer is correct, but other user might not. I suggest you add at least the names of the series those characters are featured in. ;)

Comment: Do he adopted Carrie or Cassandra?

Comment: @TerryMcGinnis - I've seen claims that he did, indeed, adopt Cassandra - however, post-Flashpoint, I'm not certain of her status.

Comment: @RDFozz his adoption thing is very contradictory for me, I will also research more soon to update my answer

Comment: @TerryMcGinnis - Chronologically, I believe you're correct, that Tim was the first Robin he actually adopted. Note that back in the 1940s, actually adopting a kid as a single father wasn't normally done; hence, the whole "ward of Bruce Wayne" thing, where he presumably became Dick's legal guardian, sans adoption. By the time we got to Tim, adoption by single parents was actually a thing. And, with a sliding timeframe of our characters' adventure, not adopting the other orphan Robins would be (pardon the expression) a real "Dick" move. So, retconning happened. As best I recall.

Answer (score 1):

As noted by Ankit, Amanda Waller wanted to continue Batman's legacy, even if Bruce Wayne was content to fade away. So she found a couple, unbeknownst to them genetically engineered the father with Bruce's DNA, and produced Terry, in a project she named *Batman Beyond* (which is the name of the series). This is the scene with her describing the full chain of events in the final episode of the series.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I was sure he had five sons and a daughter. Only 2 children were biologically related to him which was the daughter Helena Wayne (alias: huntress daughter of Catwoman and batman) as well as Damian Wayne (alias: 4th robin son of Talia al Ghul and batman) then you have the adoptive sons of the brave batman Tim Drake and Richard (Dick) Grayson both parents were killed and both were acrobats and performed in circuses the first robin was Dick who is the oldest then you have the second robin Jason Todd who was the third adoptive son batman found but unlike Tim Drake and Richard (Dick) Grayson he was not an acrobat and his father was instead a criminal and mother overdosed leaving him on the streets where batman took him in.

Comment: Helena Wayne is from alternate universe (Earth 2) and if i am not worng then he only adopted  Tim Drake (Robin).

Answer (score 0):

According to Justice League Unlimited, both Terry McGinnis and his younger brother Matt are sons of Bruce Wayne. This was genetically engineered by Amanda Waller through a fake flu shot.

This is backed up by Wikipedia's information on Terry McGinnis (" this would make Bruce the biological father of Terry and his younger brother Matt McGinnis") .

Supposedly this twist was created to explain why Warren and Mary McGinnis have light hair but both sons had black hair like Bruce.

Answer (score -1):

Batman has a son with Talia (Damian), a daughter with Selena (Helena), twin sons with Selena (Thomas and Bruce Jr.), and 3 adopted sons ( Dick, Jason and Tim), and 1 adopted daughter (Cassandra), and of course the half- son Terry.

Comment: Do you have any references for this?  Where did you learn of these?

Answer (score -2):

23

Oh god, umm let me go down the list of who I know. 4 Robins (Dick Grayson, Jason Todd, Tim Drake, Damien Wayne) 3 girls (Stephanie Brown, Cassandra Cain, Helena Wayne) apparently he adopts this child named Duke Thomas and according to an article I read earlier he had 17 bio children including Helena and Damian so minus two = 15. Please note that these numbers aren't taking into consideration universe or anything of the sort. So 4+3+1+15=23, not counting other characters that can be considered part of the batfam.

Comment: Your answer would be improved by links to sources for your information.